# How would I mathematically model this curve from Sonic the Hedgehog?

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling, cubics

[image]

Hey guys!

I'm looking at the S-Curve from the first Sonic the Hedgehog game. Out of interest, I would like to know how to mathematically model this? I'm not sure, but I suspect that it may some sort of cubic? Any one know how to definitively figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe two one-third circles?

Comment: Splines/Bezier curves are good, and are common in computer graphics